# Кнопки для прокрутки ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Есть ViewPager с 3 фрагментами, которые должны скроллиться по нажатию на кнопки – влево и вправо. Я хочу, чтобы на Фрагменте1 кнопка "влево" не показывалась, на Фрагменте2 показывались все кнопки, а на Фрагменте три не показывалась кнопка "вправо".

До этого, я делал тоже самое, только для 2 фрагментов:

```
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Но как сделать такое же условие, но только для 3 фрагментов?

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить индекс текущего фрагмента во ViewPager с помощью

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

И количество элементов во ViewPager с помощью

```
viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()
```

Тогда можно обновить код, отвечающие за видимость кнопок следующим образом:

```
button2.setVisibility(viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0? View.VISIBLE: View.INVISIBLE); //Кнопка, переключающая влево
button.setVisibility(viewPager.getCurrentItem() != viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1? View.VISIBLE: View.INVISIBLE); //Кнопка, переключающая вправо
```